# Facebook like and recommendation button

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-recommendations

I am integrating facebook like/recommend button on website "panjabiwave.com"

For recommend there is url ex. panjabiwave.com/video/22

Link for checking the recommendation is panjabiwave.com/videorecommend.

But the problem is when a user recommend a video .it is not reflected on the 
panjabiwave.com/videorecommend link

Please suggest where i am doing wrong

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Recommend is only used for one single url at a time.  There is no way to specify the url being recommended and then another for a specific url that the user will land on.  Your best bet for passing the video # to the videorecommend page like

`http://panjabiwave.com/videorecommend/22` which then can disaply the correct og meta tags (ogp.me) for the video that's really located at `http://panjabiwave.com/video/22`